# Errors while reading bmp files with EasyBMP

Tags: c++, image, bmp

i am novice in reading bmp files with c++ as data and i am using [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net) library to do that easyly. i am facing some errors.

here is cpp code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cmath>
# include <algorithm>
# include <vector>
# include "EasyBMP.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    freopen ("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen ("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    BMP NewImage;
    NewImage.SetSize (640, 480);
    NewImage.SetBitDepth(32);
    BMP AnotherImage;
    AnotherImage.ReadFromFile("logo.bmp");
    cout<<"File info:"<<'\n';
    cout<<AnotherImage.TellWidth()<<"X"<<AnotherImage.TellHeight()<<
        " at "<<AnotherImage.TellBitDepth()<<" BPP"<<'\n';


    return 0;
}
```

and here is errors:

http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1410/63/987bc0310ce4.png

(sry dont have enough reputation to upload photos here)

cant you tell me what can i do to erase this errors?
thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't linking the library.

Comment: concretely? what else should i do?

Comment: user657267 thanks for your comment! problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the linker isn't finding the implementation of the library methods. Based on the [EasyBMP documentation](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/download.html#Documentation), it looks like you have to compile the library cpp file yourself alongside your project code. Most likely you forgot to copy the cpp file to your project directory, or depending what IDE you're using, you might need to manually add the file to the project so the compiler and linker can find it.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. I am using Microsoft visual studio 2010, I had all EasyBMP header and CPP files in directory but haven't included this files in project. Thanks again :)